# What events fire with am iOS Low Battery warning? It's resetting my app

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a sensitive app the client wants to logout when it enters the background and show the login screen when it enters the foreground.  It seems to make the user relogin when they get a low battery warning at 20, 10 and 5%.  Has anyone encountered this or coded around it?  I am coming up empty in all my searches for events that occur when the low battery warning is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you need to move your logout logic from [`-applicationWillResignActive:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillResignActive%3a) or `-applicationDidBecomeActive` to [`-applicationDidEnterBackground:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidEnterBackground%3a) or `applicationWillEnterForeground` in your App Delegate.

If your app does not need to support backgrounding then the best option may be to disable it by setting [`UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW23) to `YES` in the App's plist.

Comment: This seems to be half of it, the other half is applicationWillEnterForeground and applicationDidBecomeActive. I am trying to figure that out and I have no way to drain my battery down to figure out which is firing.

Comment: Use `applicationWillEnterForeground`. I've updated my answer. WillResignActive and DidBecomeActive are fired on system notifications like when the pre iOS 5 SMS notifications came in, and in your case the 10% and 20% warnings.

Comment: @fizgig I also added another option. It seems like your application may not even need to have backgrounding enabled.

Comment: I am still getting bug reports about this issue, I will ask the client if that is OK.  applicationWillEnterForeground is not firing on a phone that is iPhone 4,OS = 4.3.3, on my 4s 5.1 and on the simulator it works perfectly.